# How to pass address from app to google maps not just latitude and longitude in swift

Tags: swift, google-maps

I am new in swift and I am facing problem to show address in google maps. I am only able to show latitude and longitude.

```swift
if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(Float(self.lat)!),\(Float(self.lon)!)&directionsmode=driving")! as URL)
}
```

[image]

This code showing address as shown in the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the query parameter `q` with `comgooglemaps` scheme like this

```
let address = "" //Replace with address to open

//Replace line breaks and white spaces in the address with queryable values
let queryableAddress = address.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: " ").replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")

if let url = URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?q=\(queryableAddress)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code

```
    let firstAddress = "your, local address, here"

    let testURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "comgooglemaps-x-callback://")!

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(testURL as URL) {
        if let address = firstAddress.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed) {
            let directionsRequest: String = "comgooglemaps-x-callback://" + "?daddr=\(address)" + "&x-success=sourceapp://?resume=true&directionsmode=driving"
            let directionsURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: directionsRequest)!
            let optionsKeyDictionary = [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey(rawValue: "universalLinksOnly"): NSNumber(value: true)]
            UIApplication.shared.open(directionsURL as URL, options: optionsKeyDictionary, completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Can't use comgooglemaps-x-callback:// on this device.")
    }
```

Also you need to add following in your Info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>comgooglemaps-x-callback</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score -1):

It will open google map if installed in your device and added url scheme in your project otherwise open default apple map with provided latitude and longitude

```
func openMapWithLatLng(dLat: Double, dLng: Double) {
    if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://?daddr=\(dLat),\(dLng)&directionsmode=driving&zoom=14&views=traffic")!, options: [:]
                , completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://?daddr=\(dLat),\(dLng)&directionsmode=driving&zoom=14&views=traffic")!)
        }
    }else {
        let url = "http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=\(dLat),\(dLng)"

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: url)!, options: [:]
                , completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: url)!, options: [:]
                    , completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add below scheme in your Info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```